# How does transclusion on Angular UI Bootstrap's <tab> directive work?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-transclude, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I'm currently trying to create a directive that has two transcluded sections and have been unsuccessful so far. Now I discovered that the `tab` directive of Angular UI Bootstrap does exactly that! Unfortunately, the angular trickery that they pull off [in their source code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js) is apparently too advanced for my understanding.

In [the examples](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs), they have the following code:

```
<tabset>
  <tab select="alertMe()">
    <tab-heading>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
    </tab-heading>
    I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

This is exactly what I need. Can someone explain to me the steps that I need to take, so that the `<tab-heading>` content is transcluded in one spot, and the other stuff in another?

Things I don't understand in the sources:

- There is no directive `tabHeading` only a `tabHeadingTransclude`. How is the `<tab-heading>` element found, then? I also don't see a query for such elements anywhere.
- I also don't understand the two transclude-directives `tabContentTransclude` and `tabHeadingTransclude`.

Answer (score 1):

You **ALMOST** had it when you were looking at the `tabHeadingTransclude` directive.  A few lines down is the `tabContentTransclude` directive.  Take a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js#L419-L428).

Ultimately, the content of either the `tab-heading` attribute or the `<tab-heading>` directive is placed inside the `{{heading}}` expression in the `tab` template [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/tabs/tab.html).

You can glean this from the `link` function in the `tabContentTransclude` directive:  We set the value of the node (the `tab-heading` attribute or the `<tab-heading>` directive) on `tab.headingElement` which we are watching in the `tabHeadingTransclude` directive.  And when it changes, we update the template.